# Large set of data, DataTables render time awful

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x, datatables

I have a view that displays a set of data of about 3000+ records (multiple objects combined into a QuerySet. The result is rendered into a table using DataTables but the render time is terrible - 15 seconds at least.

I dug deeper into DataTables and found deferRender API option together with AJAX thing. As I never used it before I'd like to ask for guidance on how to approach in my particular case. Below are views.py and template with DataTables.

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    clients = Client.objects.all().prefetch_related('loan_set', 'loan_set__case_set')
    return render(request, 'app/index.html',
                  {'clients': clients})
```

index.html:

```
            <table id="case_list" class="display">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Imię i nazwisko</td>
                    <td>Edycja</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for c in clients %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ c.firstName }}&nbsp;{{ c.lastName }}</td>
                    {% if c.editLock %}
                    <td><i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg" style="color:Red" title="W edycji przez:&nbsp;{{ c.lockedBy }}"></i>&nbsp;{{ c.lockedBy }}</td>
                    {% else %}
                    <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <td><a href="/edit/{{ c.pk }}" name="c_id"><i class="fas fa-pen-square fa-2x" style="color:green"></i></a></td>                            
                    </form>    
                    {% endif %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#case_list').DataTable( {
        deferRender: true
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side).

```
    $('#case_list').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{yourdata_url}"
    } );
```

In your view, you have to send the data in json format. Note that you need to do the search etc with your logic in the view.

I would also look into django-datatable-view package.